# RabbitMQ/MassTransit Timeout

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

We are using RabbitMQ and MassTransit to exchange messages between publishers and consumers. Sometimes we are getting below exception message and then our all message transmissions are suddenly stopping. I am posting also our bus configuration code below.

```
    One or more errors occurred. (Timeout waiting for response, 
RequestId: 00c60000-0aff-0242-e641-08d6a323ec24)", 
"MassTransit.RequestTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for response, 
RequestId: 00c60000-0aff-0242-e641-08d6a323ec24   at MassTransit.Clients.ResponseHandlerConnectHandle`1.GetTask()   
at MassTransit.Clients.ClientRequestHandle`1.HandleFault()   at MassTransit.Clients.ResponseHandlerConnectHandle`1.GetTask()   
at MassTransit.Clients.RequestClient`1.GetResponse[T](TRequest message, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestTimeout timeout)
```

**Here is our bus configuration**

```
service.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                if (startQuartz) 
                {
                    startQuartz = false;
                    MicroServiceConfig.MicroServiceHost.StartScheduledServices();
                }
                var config = provider.GetRequiredService<SLOTServerConfiguration>();
                var vh = GetVirtualHost(config);
                var url = config.RabbitMQHost + (config.RabbitMQHost.EndsWith("/") ? "" : "/") + vh;
                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(url), hst =>
               {
                   hst.Username(config.RabbitMQUserName);
                   hst.Password(config.RabbitMQPassword);
               });
                if (!isApi)
                {
                    cfg.AddReceiveEndpoint(host, provider, service, isApi);
                    host.ConnectConsumeObserver(new UserObserver());
                    host.ConnectSendObserver(new ErrorObserver());
                }
            }));
            service.AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
            service.AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
            service.AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
            service.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();

            service.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                var method = x.GetType().GetMethod("AddConsumer");
                foreach (var item in RegisteredTypes)
                {
                    method.MakeGenericMethod(item.ConsumerType).Invoke(x, new object[0]);
                }
            });
        }

        private static void AddReceiveEndpoint(this IRabbitMqBusFactoryConfigurator cfg, IRabbitMqHost host, IServiceProvider provider, IServiceCollection service, bool registerClient)
        {
            var queueName = DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc().ToString() + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MicroServiceConfig.MicroServiceHost.ServiceNames).GetHashCode();
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, queueName, e =>
            {
                e.AutoDelete = true;
                e.PrefetchCount = 16;
                e.UseMessageRetry(x => x.Interval(2, 100));
                e.LoadFrom(provider);
            });
        }

        private static string GetVirtualHost(SLOTServerConfiguration config)
        {

            var vh = config.RabbitMQVirtualHost;
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(vh))
            {
                vh = Environment.MachineName;
            }
        }
```

Update :
Below you can find the publisher and consumer code blocks

```
var res = ThreadClient.GetResponse<AddExternalOutboundOrderListRequestModel, OutboundOrderResponseItem>(
                       _requestClient,
                       new ServerRequest<AddExternalOutboundOrderListRequestModel> { Model = model, Token = Request.Headers["token"] }
                       );
                var ret = BaseResponseModel.Ok(res.Data, Request.Headers["RequestID"]);
                ret.ExceptionMessage = res.ThreadExceptions;
                return ret;
```

Consumer :

```
public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ServerRequest<AddExternalOutboundOrderListRequestModel>> context)
        {
            var response = _outboundOrderWorkFlow.Add(context.Message.Model);
            ServerResponse<OutboundOrderResponseItem> res = new ServerResponse<OutboundOrderResponseItem>
            {
                Data = response
            };
            context.Respond(res);
            return Task.Delay(0);
        }
```

Comment: The error comes from the request-response client, but you have shown no code how you use it.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code.

Comment: I'd highly recommend reading the container documentation and using that setup, you're configure code overly complex: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/msdi.html -- also, there is an AddConsumer(Type consumerType) you can use.